# Would a Command spell cause a target to teleport away?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, forced-movement

My 9th level Bard character failed his save against a Command to Flee, which states that "The target spends its turn moving away from you by the fastest available means." Would that include casting spells like Dimension Door? Or would it only mean pure movement, not spellcasting to flee?

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate since it has been asked before. Don't worry, duplicates are generally a good thing, they can help to point users to the answers they are looking for.